# Difference in the value of a tag in HTML

Tags: html

I am not sure if this is a very silly question but lately I have been having this in my mind. I want to know if there is a difference between

```
<button value = "SomeValue"></button>
```

and

```
<button>SomeValue</button>
```

Is there something that I really need to understand with the way these tags work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you acually tried it?

**The first one:**

```
<button value="SomeValue"></button>
```

Does not show a label on the button

**The second one:**

```
<button>SomeValue</button>
```

does

Comment: Shows a label for me.

Answer (score 1):

`<button>SomeValue</button>` is the correct syntax for a clickable button.
 Alternatively, `<button value="SomeValue"></button>` does not, with the button not displaying the label. the value attribute was originally made for the input tag back in HTML4

```
HTML4:
<input type="submit" value="Some Value"/>

HTML5:
<button>Some Value</button>
```

Both of these are equivalent and backwards compatible

Answer (score 1):

```
<button value="SomeValue"></button>
```

This is an [html attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). Defines a default value which will be displayed in the element on page load.

valid elements to have value attribute.

```
<button>, <option>, <input>, <li>, <meter>, <progress>, <param>
```

In your second example:

```
<button>SomeValue</button>
```

This one is the content of the element(in this case is plain text). Other than these you can notice those differences for example if you handle this elements in javasacript. For example:

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var btn2 = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];
console.log(btn1.value); //prins someValue
console.log(btn2.innerHTML); //prins SomeValue
```

```html
<button value="someValue"></button>
<button>SomeValue</button>
```

In [empty elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element) like `inputs` the attribute `value` is also and the display value:

```html
<input type="text" value="someValue" />
```

**References**

[Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)